# React Native how to load Modal with dynamique data from any child Component

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-redux

Hello i am start working inside a mobile application with React Native and i have a listview (each item is a separate Component ) and when i click in a item  i would like to load a Modal with dynamic data
My Question is how to create it without creating a modal for each item of the list ?

Answer (score 0):

When click an item, set a state then pass your state to modal

Comment: the too component (item list and Modal ) is separated

Comment: @AbdelkadreElMaghri use states of item list as Modal's props

Comment: can you give me an example or tuto for that please
NB: i need to load modal from a different ListView